# Are the binary digits of the sequence of the prime numbers correlated?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $p_n\geq 3$ be the $n$th prime number with the binary expansion $p_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{nk}2^k$  ($b_{nk}\in\{0,1\}$). Let's write $q_{nk} = 1-2b_{nk}$.

> **Question:** Is it true that for $k,l\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=2}^N q_{nk}q_{(n+j)l} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1; & k=l\hspace{2mm}\textrm{ and  }\hspace{2mm}j=0, \\ 0;& \textrm{ otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$

The motivation behind this question is merely curiosity. This preliminary observation from a simple Matlab/Octave/Scilab script is perhaps known to the knowledgeable people in the field. Any references will be much appreciated.

Comment: Conjecturally, there is a slight bias, but it is lower order and vanishes in the limit you indicate.  However, proving things rigorously is probably out of reach of current technology. https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you for graciously replying this post and for the reference you've linked, which I need time to truly understand and see the intuition behind.